# Function having similar behavior as tanh.

Tags: functions

I am trying to look for a list of functions which have behavior similar to thehyperbolic tangent, i.e. as $x\rightarrow -\infty$ we have some value say let it be $a$ and when $x\rightarrow \infty$ we have some other value say it be $b$. In between the two ends of the $x$-axis. I don't care how the function behaves, whether it be oscillatory or something complicated, but it has to be continuous and arbitrarily differentiable. Something like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rz2q0.gif)
I have 3 other examples of functions having such behavior

$\bullet \tan^{-1}x$

$\bullet \frac{x}{\sqrt{(1+x^2)}}$

$\bullet \frac{1}{1+P[e^{x}]}$, where $P[u]$ means a well behaved polynomial of $u$.

You can leave $\coth x$ and $\cot^{-1}x$ aside because I can get similar behavior from above function by shifting them about $y$-axis and reflecting them about $x$- or $y$-axis.

Comment: Another example is the sigmoid function $\sigma(x) = 1/(1 + e^{-x})$, which is used in logistic regression and has been used as an activation function in neural networks.

Comment: @littleO Note that $\sigma(x)=\frac12\left(1+\tanh\frac{x}{2}\right)$.

Comment: You can take the cumulative distribution function of your favorite distribution on $\mathbb{R}$ (normal, T-, Cauchy, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

We'll focus on functions with $a=-1,\,b=1$; we can always linearly transform later. The infinitely differentiable $f$ satisfying $f(-1)=-1,\,f(1)=1$ allow us to compose a suitable function to another one, so we can not only get infinitely many solutions but arbitrary complexity of their definitions. For example, we can go from $\tanh x$ to $\tanh^N x$ with positive odd $N$, or $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\tanh^N x\right)$ while we're at it. Or how about $g\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\tanh^N x\right)\right)$ with $g(x):=\frac{2h(x)-h(1)-h(-1)}{h(1)-h(-1)}$, for infinitely differentiable $h$ with $h(-1)\ne h(1)$? So it's very, very open-ended.